# GridBagLayout in eclipse view

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

Dear StackOverflow readers!

I want to create eclipse plugin with new view. But when I try to set layout of parent composite which, is passed to createPartControl(Composite parent) I get "The method setLayout(Layout) in the type Composite is not applicable for the arguments (GridBagLayout)" errormessage.

How can I do that?

@Override

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {       
    parent.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`enter code here`
}
```

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` belongs to `java.awt` package, whereas you are using Eclipse's SWT `Composite` (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets`).  This requires a subclass of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout`.  You will have to decide which subclass suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and usefull answer. Is there any way to use GridBagLayout in eclipse view?

Comment: In the meantime, I realized that the GridLayout and sashform is perfect for me.

Thanks for your answer!